# Set og:image fetching from db in Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger

Tags: twig, symfony-2.8, facebook-share

I need to set og properties dynamically for facebook as below code,

```
<head>
....
 <meta property="og:image" content="{{ url('homepage') }}uploads/media/images/article/{{ post.postImage1 }}" />

....
</head>
```

But {{ post.postImage1 }} returns file name ( I can see it in view source ) which is come from DB ( via controller ). But in Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger not showing it and Image is not loading. How to fix this.

Comment: Did u already verify that `post` is set and contains the property `postImage1`? You can do this with `{{ dump(post) }}` when `twig`'s debug mode is on

Comment: @DarkBee I can see value in view source but in  Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger it is not showing and image is not loading

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image you are trying to use as preview for facebook?